# Power BI data source credentials problems for Power BI Web.Contents

Tags: powerbi

I am using an API call to bring data into a Power BI report.

The source is Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://fingertips.phe.org.uk/api/area_types"))

I can get the data into Power BI Desktop and refresh it just fine.  But when I publish to the Power BI Service then the connection fails (unable to connect to the remote server) when I try and enter the data source credentials (Anonymous/Public) for the Dataset.  As such, I can't set up a scheduled refresh, which is what I'd like to do.

I've read some interesting blog posts by Chris Webb on handling dynamic query parameters with Web.Contents, but my example has no dynamic components and works fine if one just calls up the URL in the web browser.

I've got other Power BI reports published in the service using similar APIs that work fine, but this fingertips API is beating me at the moment.

The full code is

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://fingertips.phe.org.uk/api/area_types")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"Id", "Name", "Short", "Class", "Sequence", "CanBeDisplayedOnMap"}, {"Column1.Id", "Column1.Name", "Column1.Short", "Column1.Class", "Column1.Sequence", "Column1.CanBeDisplayedOnMap"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

Does anyone have any ideas why, in this instance, the connection to the API from the Power BI Service should behave differently from the connection from Power BI Desktop?

Many thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 0):

You can try set "Skip test connection" for this datasource in your dataset.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/skip-test-connection-for-on-premises-and-cloud-data-sources/

https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2019/04/25/skip-test-connection-power-bi-refresh-failures/